# Firebase (Javascript)- How can a file be uploaded to firebase storage and database simultaneously?

Tags: javascript, html, function, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

In my user registration form, I want store user information in firebase database and upload file attached to firebase storage and copy the file storage url to the firebase database. The tutorial does not give good information on how to do both simultaneously. I can save information to firebase database successfully but I can't figure out how to do database and storage simultaneously. What is the best way to execute this?

```
<button ng-disabled="form-register.$invalid" class="waves-effect waves-light btn done"  onclick="registerBussiness();">
    <i class="material-icons left" >done</i> Register
</button>
```

That was the submit  button that calls the function below

```
function registerBussiness() {
    var database = firebase.database();
    var fname = document.getElementById('first-name').value;
    var lname = document.getElementById('last-name').value;
    var businessname = document.getElementById('business-name').value; 
    var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
    var password = document.getElementById('password').value;
    var industry = document.getElementById('industry').value;


    // var Author = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid
    // var ref = firebase.database().ref();
    if (email.length < 4) {
        alert('Please enter an email address.');
        return;
    }
    if (password.length < 4) {
        alert('Please enter a password.');
        return;
    }

    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password) .then(function(user) {
        var root = firebase.database().ref();
        var uid = user.uid;
        var auth = firebase.auth();
        var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();

        // Store image in firebase storage 

        ("file").on("change", function(event) {

        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
        var file = event.target.files[0];

        var metadata = {
            'contentType': file.type
        };

        // Push to child path.
        // [START oncomplete]
        storageRef.child('images/' + file.name).put(file, metadata).then(function(snapshot) {
            console.log('Uploaded', snapshot.totalBytes, 'bytes.');
            console.log(snapshot.metadata);
            var url = snapshot.downloadURL;
            console.log('File available at', url);
            // [START_EXCLUDE]
            document.getElementById('linkbox').innerHTML = '<a href="' +  url + '">Click For File</a>';
            // [END_EXCLUDE]
        }).catch(function(error) {
            // [START onfailure]
            console.error('Upload failed:', error);
            // [END onfailure]
        });
    })

    // [END oncomplete]

    var postData = {
        BusinessName: businessname,
        email: email,
        profileImageUrl: url,
        Category: industry,
    };

    // var newPostKey = firebase.database().ref().child('Businesses').push().key;     // Get a key for a new Job Post.

    var updates = {};

    updates['/BusinessCategories/' + industry + "/" + uid ] = postData;
    updates['/Businesses/' + uid] = postData;

    return firebase.database().ref().update(updates); 

})
```

when I filled the form and click to upload information it displayed this error "firebase.js:88 Uncaught TypeError: "file".on is not a function"

Comment: what is `("file")` what is the value of this? isn't firebase `file.on("change"...`??? I think you might be confused between jquery `$("file").on("change"...`?